Movie with surreal talk about Nietzsche books
In the '80, I saw a scene of a movie. Unfortunately, I only saw that scene, but I still remember it and I would like to see the whole movie. Here is what I saw.
There is a man who is having a job interview. The interviewer asks him about one of his previous activities, cultural cooperator (or something similar) in a public institution. Here is the dialogue (or something similar, I heard the Italian dubbed version):
Man: "For example, we were sending Nietzsche to an African country"
Interviewer: "But God said that Nietzsche is dead"
Man: "Yes, that's why we sent his books instead".
The tone was surreal. The title was long and contained something about "nuclear". It was dubbed in Italian but have the feeling that it was done in Europe, maybe in France. Does anyone remember the movie?

Are you sure on the 80's? There was a 2007 movie: When Nietzsche Wept, based on a novel from 1992.
